# Open the pdf without saving it ,during url to pdf conversion using ironpdf

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using ironpdf for converting url to pdf. Conversion is successful, but I have to save the document at a location. Is it possible to just display as a memory stream or byte array?

```
            string authority = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
            string val = "http://"+authority + "/Report/PrintReport.aspx?ID=" + vciInfoReportid;
            string fileName = "url.pdf";
            string fileloc = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"+fileName);
            Renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(val).SaveAs(fileloc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. There is a inbuilt method for it

```
            //Conversion of the ASPX file into PDF

            MemoryStream rend=Renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(val).Stream;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

            // let the browser know how to open the PDF document, attachment or inline, and the file name
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename=Print.pdf; size={1}",
              "attachment", rend.Length.ToString()));

            // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(rend.ToArray());

            // call End() method of HTTP response to stop ASP.NET page processing
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

More information can be found in this [ASPX to PDF Tutorial](https://ironpdf.com/tutorials/aspx-to-pdf/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try Google Docs :**

Open your pdf in google viewer without download.

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://"+authority + "/Report/PrintReport.aspx?ID=" + vciInfoReportid
```